# Existence of models $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{M}' $ elementary equivalent $R$ such that $Q$ is dense in $\mathcal{M}$ but not in $ \mathcal{M}' $

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

Sorry for asking but I'm really stuck, I have absolutely no idea of where start solving exercices 3. Can someone give to me some hints? Down I say what is my idea.

Let $ L = \{ 0,1,<,+, \cdot \} $ be a language of first order containing the symbol $=$. Let $ R = \left< \mathbb{R} ,0,1,<,+, \cdot \right> $ and let $ Q =\left< \mathbb{Q} ,0,1,<,+, \cdot \right> $ be the $L$-structures corresponding to the real and rational number with the usual interpretation.

1. Existe a $L$-structure that is countable elementary equivalent to $R$ ? (Easy with downward SK theorem)
2. Exsite a $L$-structure that is equipotent to $\mathbb{R}$ that is elementary equivalent to $Q$? (Easy with upward SK theorem)
3. Prove that there exsits a $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{M}' $ structure such that

i) The domain of $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{M}' $ is countable

ii) $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{M}' $ are elementary equivalent to $R$

iii) There exsits a dense embendding of $Q$ into $\mathcal{M} $ and there is not a dense embendding of $Q$ into $\mathcal{M}'$

where a for dense embendding i mean  that $ f: Q \rightarrow \mathcal{M} $ is an embendding such that for all $a,b, \in \mathcal{M} $ if $a < b$ exsits $q \in Q$ such that $a < f(q) < b $.

**My ideas for** 3.
Since any formula parametrized in $Q$ is of finite height (the height of its tree of decomposition) moreover for a given height there are only countable many formula since $Q$ is countable. Then we have only countable many $ \varphi $ parametrized in $Q$  such that $ R \models \varphi $ and $ Q \not\models \varphi $. Let's define some enumeration of these formule, and consider the set $ T = \{ \varphi_n : n \in \mathbb{N}, \varphi_n \text{ parametrized in } Q \} $, i.e. $ R \models \varphi $ and $ Q \not\models \varphi $ if and only if $ \varphi \in T $ or $ \varphi $ is not parametrized in $Q$. Then consider the theory of $ Q$, i.e. $ Th(Q)= \{ \varphi : \varphi \text{ closed formula such that } Q \models \varphi \} $. Clearly $ R \models  Th(Q) \cup T $, by upward SK theorem we have that exist a model $ \mathcal{M} $ that is countable. Similary we have that $Th(R) $ possesses by upward SK-theorem a model $ \mathcal{M} ' $ that is countable. My idea is to shows that these models $ \mathcal{M} $ , $ \mathcal{M} ' $ satisfies property iii) but I don't know how and also I don't know if my intuition is correct.

Comment: Can't you make a non-Archimedean ordered field which is elementarily equivalent to $\mathbb R And can't you also make it countable? That would work for your $\mathcal M'$ wouldn't it?

Comment: hi 3m0o. I'm not sure I understand your attempt at 3; can you explain what it means for a formula $\varphi$ to be "parametrized in $Q$", and what it means for it to have "finite height"? anyway, you write that $R\models \operatorname{Th}(Q)$, but this is not the case; for example, we have $Q\models\neg\exists x(x^2=1+1)$, whence $\neg\exists x(x^2=1+1)\in\operatorname{Th}(Q)$, but $R\models\exists x(x^2=1+1)$

Comment: for a different solution, @bof's approach is the cleanest. (if you don't know what it means for an ordered field $(F,<)$  to be non-Archimedean, it just means there exists $c\in F$ with $c>n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}\subset F$.) here's a slightly further hint along those lines: if $F$ is any field of characteristic $0$, how many different field homomorphisms $\mathbb{Q}\to F$ are there? so, if $\mathcal{M}'$ is a structure elementarily equivalent to $R$, how many possible embeddings $Q\to\mathcal{M}'$ can there be to check the density of?

Comment: I think that there are only 2 homomorphisms, the identity and the zero homomorphism (everything is send to zero). Only the identity is injective. Anyway maybe it sufficies to take $\operatorname{Th}(R) \cup T $, where $T = \{ \varphi_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \} $, and where for all $n \in \mathbb{N} $ we take $ \varphi_n : \exists x (\underbrace{1+\ldots+1}_{n-\text{times}} < x) $. But it doesn't seem to me that they are elementary equivalent. And also how to show that there exist an **ordered** model of this theory?

Comment: For "parametrized" in $Q$ I meant that since $Q$ is a substructure of $R$. Two substructure are said elementary substructure if for any $ a_1,\ldots,a_n \in \left| Q \right|$ we have $ R \models \varphi[a_1,\ldots, a_n ] $ iff $ Q \models \varphi[a_1,\ldots,a_n] $. In this case they are not substrucutre elementary structures. And this kind of formula are countable since the parameter are in $Q$. For height I meant the height of the tree of decomposition of the formula. Clearly there are some formula that are not parametrized and still $R \models \varphi$ but $Q \not\models \varphi$.

Comment: Maybe I can add a symbol to the theory $ L' = L \cup \{ w \} $ and taking just $ T' = Th(R) \cup \{ \varphi_n \} $. Then T' it is finitely satisfaible.  Hence by compact. thm is satisfaible thus there is a model $\mathcal{M}'$. Since any model of $T'$ is a model of $Th(R)$, by downward L-S, we may assume that $\mathcal{M}'$ is countable. Then by a corollary of the compactness Thm, $T' \models \varphi $ if and only if there exist a finite subset $T_f'$ such that $ T_f' \models \varphi $. But any finite subset is finite subset of $ Th(R)$ adding the finite part of $\{ \varphi_n \} \subset T_f'$

Comment: For $ \mathcal{M} $, it is sufficient to take the model of point 1. then we have a natural  embedding $ g : \mathcal{M} \rightarrow R $, then it sufficient to take any embedding $ h : Q \rightarrow R $ and composite with the left inverse $ g^{-1} $, hence $f= g^{-1} \circ h : Q \rightarrow \mathcal{M}$ is a dense embedding by the density of $ \mathbb{Q} $ in $\mathbb{R} $.